# Error parsing package when installing my app

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2017

So I get this weird error when I try to install the signed apk file on my android Xperia z3 device. I have sat with this for 6 hours now and I don't find a solution to all the posts from earlier problems. What is actually going on? downloading the apk file from a project in the android studio I made was 1 button click. And here with xamarin????

I really need help with this. The project runs on emulator inside vs on both debug and release options. no errors from the output.

These are the set targets for max and min android versions. https://gyazo.com/fc82fd6c6edced442bd8a790166d3e03
My Xperia is running on 6.0.3

"There was a problem parsing the package".

Please help

Comment: How do you generate the apk? and if you install the unsign apk it will give this error, how do you sign it?

Comment: I sign it with the archieve in xamarin. With ad hoc

Comment: I think there are something went wrong when you sign the apk. You could follow this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/deploy-test/signing/manually-signing-the-apk) to sign it manually. Since you have already run the app in the emulator, you could get the sign the apk in `...\projcetfolder\bin\Release`

Comment: Okay so getting the signed.apk file in "projectsfolder/bin/Release" folder will work on my xperia? Do i need to rename it? or should i just grab that signed apk file and just try to install it on my xperia?

Comment: Okay so i took that file as it is and installed it on my phone and it works great! Dude litterly. Make an answer so i can give you the green bok answer. You have helped me out so much in this. Well done sir. Just to give note, i did try that earlier but i did change some code in the androidmanifest.xml file , that maybe did it but yet again. thanks alot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "There was a problem parsing the package".

This error usually happens when install the unsign apk. 
I think there are something went wrong when you sign the apk. You could follow this [tutorial : Manually Signing the APK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/deploy-test/signing/manually-signing-the-apk) to sign it manually. Since you have already run the app in the emulator, you could get the signed apk in `...\projcetfolder\bin\Release` and use it install your app.

Comment: I downloaded signed apk but it still shows the same error.

Answer (score 0):

If renaming does not work check android manifest file. I had missed

```
 <intent>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
    <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
  </intent>
```

Missed those *and it resulted in that issue

Answer (score 0):

recently had this problem with Visual Studio 2022. After creating an archive, on the archive manager screen, there is an Open Folder button which goes to a folder that contains an APK. I believe that apk file may be unsigned (not sure). After copying that file it does not install correctly on the target device. My solution was to go to another folder where correct apk file was generated which in my case was two folder levels above the folder where VS2022 open folder button was taking me too.