# Xamarin android download and install apk programatically

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android

So I have a button that verifies for updates and when I click it I want it to download and install the apk but I keep getting the error `There was a problem parsing the package`.

Downloading ->

```cs
          var imagePath = Path.Combine(Android.OS.Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryDownloads).ToString(), "abcFichaObrasUpdate");
          using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
          {
            try
            {
              if (!Directory.Exists(imagePath.ToString()))
              {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(imagePath.ToString());
              }
              Uri uri = new Uri(remoteUri);
              client.DownloadFileCompleted += (s, e) => Extract(s, e, progress);
              client.DownloadProgressChanged += (s, e) => ProgessChanged(s, e);
              client.DownloadFileAsync(uri, imagePath + "/" + "update.apk");
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
              throw;
            }
          }
```

So when the download is finished it save's in a path something like that `/storage/emulated/0/Download/abcFichaObrasUpdate/update.apk`

Instaling ->

```cs
        Java.IO.File updatePath = new Java.IO.File(Android.OS.Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryDownloads).ToString(), "abcFichaObrasUpdate");
        Java.IO.File toInstall = new Java.IO.File(updatePath, "update.apk");
        Android.Net.Uri apkUri = Android.Support.V4.Content.FileProvider.GetUriForFile(Application.Context,
                AppInfo.PackageName + ".provider",
                toInstall);
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionView);
        intent.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.GrantReadUriPermission);
        intent.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.ClearTop);
        intent.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);
        intent.PutExtra(Intent.ExtraNotUnknownSource, true);
        intent.SetData(apkUri);
        Application.Context.StartActivity(intent);
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```cs
    <provider android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider" android:authorities="com.abcbraga.abcfichaobras.provider" android:exported="false" android:grantUriPermissions="true">
      <meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS" android:resource="@xml/filepaths" />
    </provider>
```

filepaths.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
  <external-path
    name="external"
    path="." />
  <external-files-path
      name="external_files"
      path="." />
  <files-path
      name="files"
      path="." />
</paths>
```

But when it gets the apkUri it transforms it to `{content://com.abcbraga.abcfichaobras.provider/external/Download/abcFichaObrasUpdate/update.apk}`
and when it tries to start the install activity it just throws the error, I think the problem is in the URI.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Install Application programmatically on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4604239/install-application-programmatically-on-android)

Comment: No it doesn't answer my question

Comment: Can you install the apk manually without using the code? I researched and find a thread said that [This error usually happens when install the unsign apk.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50049652/error-parsing-package-when-installing-my-app).

Comment: Manually I'm able to install it and the apk is signed

Comment: How about try the code in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45014498/xamarin-android-7-install-apk-programmatically)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make it work I changed provider
From android support v4

```
<provider android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider" android:authorities="com.abcbraga.abcfichaobras.provider" android:exported="false" android:grantUriPermissions="true">
   <meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS" android:resource="@xml/filepaths" />
</provider>
```

To androidx core content

```
<provider android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider" android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider" android:exported="false" android:grantUriPermissions="true">
    <meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS" android:resource="@xml/file_provider_paths" />
</provider>
```