# Install APK from Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, android, .net, xamarin.forms, android-fileprovider

I want to install the APK file from the storage directory using **FileProvider** in VS2019 - .Net Standard2.1 and Target Framework API28 for Android. But I got the error `"The name 'FileProvider' does not exist in the current context".` Even am try to change .Net 2.0 same error.

```
Java.IO.File file = new Java.IO.File(filepath);
                    if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.N)
                    {
                        Android.Net.Uri URIAPK = FileProvider.GetUriForFile(Android.App.Application.Context, Android.App.Application.Context.ApplicationContext.PackageName + ".provider", filepath);
                        Intent intS = new Intent(Intent.ActionInstallPackage);
                        intS.SetData(URIAPK);
                        intS.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.GrantReadUriPermission);
                        Android.App.Application.Context.StartActivity(intS);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Android.Net.Uri URIAPK = Android.Net.Uri.FromFile(filepath);
                        Intent intS = new Intent(Intent.ActionView);
                        intS.SetDataAndType(URIAPK, "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
                        intS.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);
                        Android.App.Application.Context.StartActivity(intS);
                    }
```

I try to use namespace `"Using Android.v4.content.FileProvider;"` still errors because missing .dll so, when am going to install Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat Nuget got the Suppression Error

> NU1202 Package Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat 28.0.0.3 is not
> compatible with netstandard2.1 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.1). Package
> Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat 28.0.0.3 supports:
>
> - monoandroid60 (MonoAndroid,Version=v6.0)
> - monoandroid70 (MonoAndroid,Version=v7.0)
> - monoandroid71 (MonoAndroid,Version=v7.1)
> - monoandroid80 (MonoAndroid,Version=v8.0)
> - monoandroid81 (MonoAndroid,Version=v8.1)
> - monoandroid90 (MonoAndroid,Version=v9.0)

Give me the solution or any other methodology for Install APK file.

Comment: I don't know about installing APK, but given a compatability error, I would [use AndroidX](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/androidx), rather than the older Support.Compat nugets. This requires some namespace changes, as described in that link.  The androidx compat nuget is `Xamarin.AndroidX.AppCompat`.

Comment: googling `xamarin android install apk programmatically`, I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64431757/199364) that uses AndroidX. See the question of that answer, for the rest of the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But I got the error "The name 'FileProvider' does not exist in the
> current context"

For this error, please refer to the correct package. In common,we suggest to use the latest nuget `Xamarin.AndroidX.AppCompat`

In code, we should import this nuget as follows:

```
using AndroidX.AppCompat.App;
using AndroidX.Core.Content;
```

The total code of `FileProvider` should be :

```
Android.Net.Uri URIAPK = AndroidX.Core.Content.FileProvider.GetUriForFile(Android.App.Application.Context, Android.App.Application.Context.ApplicationContext.PackageName + ".provider", filepath);
```

In this condition,the error "The name 'FileProvider' does not exist in the current context" will disapear.

And if you want to use the latest nuget `Xamarin.AndroidX.AppCompat`, you should Migrate your app to AndroidX, for more, you can check document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/androidx#migration-tooling .

In addition,remember to add the correct  additional configuration files to adhere to the new strict mode:

(AndroidX) Add the following to your AndroidManifest.xml inside the `<application>` tags:

```
   <provider android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider" 
          android:authorities="${applicationId}.fileprovider" 
          android:exported="false" 
          android:grantUriPermissions="true">
          
      <meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS" 
                     android:resource="@xml/file_paths"></meta-data>
</provider>
```

For more ,check:https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin#android-file-provider-setup.

**Note:**

We strongly recommend that you upgrade to the latest Visual Studio and use the newer Nugets by default to avoid migrate and compatibility problems.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable Update. ".provider" not same in AndroidManifest.xml. Secondly I'm using Dependency for fileprovider as per this https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin#android-file-provider-setup